# timeIntervalSinceDate Accuracy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I've been working on a game with an engine that updates 20 times per seconds.  I've got to point now where I want to start getting some performance figures and tweak the rendering and logic updates.  In order to do so I started to add some timing code to my game loop, implemented as follows...

```
NSDate* startTime = [NSDate date];
// Game update logic here....
// Also timing of smaller internal events
NSDate* endTime = [NSDate date];
[endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
```

I noticed however that when I timed blocks within the outer timing logic that the time they took to execute did not sum up to match the overall time taken.

So I wrote a small unit test to demonstrate the problem in which I time the overall time taken to complete the test and then 10 smaller events, here it is...

```
- (void)testThatSumOfTimingsMatchesOverallTiming {

NSDate* startOfOverallTime = [NSDate date];

// Variable to hold summation of smaller timing events in the upcoming loop...
float sumOfIndividualTimes = 0.0;
NSTimeInterval times[10] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSDate* startOfIndividualTime = [NSDate date];
    // Kill some time...
    sleep(1);
    NSDate* endOfIndividualTime = [NSDate date];
    times[i] = [endOfIndividualTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startOfIndividualTime];
    sumOfIndividualTimes += times[i];
}

NSDate* endOfOverallTime = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval overallTimeTaken = [endOfOverallTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startOfOverallTime];

NSLog(@"Sum of individual times: %fms", sumOfIndividualTimes);
NSLog(@"Overall time: %fms", overallTimeTaken);

STAssertFalse(TRUE, @"");
}
```

And here's the output...

```
Sum of individual times: 10.001377ms
Overall time: 10.016834ms
```

Which illustrates my problem quite clearly.  The overall time was 0.000012ms but the smaller events took only 0.000001ms.  So what happened to the other 0.000011ms?

Is there anything that looks particularly wrong with my code?  Or is there an alternative timing mechanism I should use?

Comment: So as kindly recommended by Ed Marty in the first answer I switched the implementation to use CACurrentMediaTime() instead of NSDate objects.  Unfortunately there's still a discrepancy between the sum of the individual times and the overall time, the discrepancy is now around 0.01ms - which is still very similar to the NSDate implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is some time required to run `[NSDate date]` and `[endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]` which probably accounts for the difference.

However, I would use `CACurrentMediaTime()` which returns a `CFTimeInterval` (which is just a double), or `mach_absolute_time()` which returns an unsigned long int.  Both of these avoid object creation and probably take less time.

Of course, you'll still be subtracting two numbers every frame, which takes time.  My suggestion to get around that would be to just use lastFrameEnd:

```
CFTimeInterval lastFrameEnd = CACurrentMediaTime();
while (true) {
  // Game update logic here....
  // Also timing of smaller internal events
  CFTimeInterval frameEnd = CACurrentMediaTime();
  CFTimeInterval duration = frameEnd - lastFrameEnd;  //Use this
  lastFrameEnd = frameEnd;
}
```

This takes into account the time taken for the end of one frame to the end of the next, including the time taken for the subtraction and method calls.

Comment: I did consider the fact that the NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate method would take some time itself, so I timed it too.  What I found was  that it took a relatively small amount of time too - maybe only 10-15% of the discrepancy.  So it looks like there's still something chewing up time...

Thanks for the CACurrentMediaTime() suggestion though, I'll switch the code over to use it and post back with my results.

Comment: Added an update to the original post.  After switching to the CACurrentMedia time implementation I'm still seeing the same behaviour.  There's an unaccounted for 0.01ms being added to my overall time that really doesn't correlate with the code that executes outside of the individual timings...

Comment: Did you also account for the time taken during the object creation of `[NSDate date]`?  Did you make the change I suggested about not using a start and end loop time?  Because there is some time spent in the increment and check of the of the loop counter as well, which is why I suggested just using the start of one frame to the start of the next.

Comment: I've accounted for the creation of the NSDate in my timings.  I hear what you're saying about the loop counter but surely it can't be that expensive an operation?  It's an order of magnitude greater than the individual time, which would seem pretty high?  Thanks!

Comment: You'd be surprised at how much time can be spent in the loop counter stuff.  Quite a lot of time can be spent there.  You could turn the for loop into a while(true) and do the loop counter manually, inside the timing to see how much it actually takes up.